# Prediction with a Nested Table and DMX

Tags: sql, sql-server, classification, business-intelligence, dmx-ssas

I'm having some trouble generating the proper SQL/DMX in order to do prediction in SQL Server 2008 Business Intelligence Development Studio. I've got the following table setup with training data.

```
Transactions
    ID (int)(primary key)
    Code (string)
Items
    ID (int)(foreign key that points to ID in Transactions table)
    Item (string)
```

I'm using the Naive Bayes classifier and what I want to do is train it so that whenever I see a specific collection of items, they allow me to predict what the "Code" field is in the Transactions table. Since I'm using a nested table, I'm sure that my SQL below is screwed up.

```
select predict([code]) from <miningModel>
    natural prediction join 
    (select 'ethernet' as Item union
     select 'panel' as Item) as foo
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I wasn't naming my aliases exactly like they were in reality, the nested portion was messed up, and a couple other things. It should've been like the following.

```
select predict([TransactionsMiningModel].[Code]) from [TransactionsMiningModel]
    natural prediction join 
    (select (
             select 'foobar' as [Item]
            ) as [Item Decomposition] ) as t
```